# Running kafka container in docker linux

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I followed these steps to running Kafka

1. `docker pull bitnami/kafka`
2. download zip code from https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python
3. `docker-compose -f ./zk-single-kafka-single.yml up`

but when i want to run kafka container, i got this error

```
Unable to find image '93e584083efc:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

i put an screenshot from mt terminal when i make zookeeper

[image]

both zookeeper and kafka couldn'd run containers

the content of zk-single-kafka-single.yml is:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.1
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9999:9999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

Comment: post the content of zk-single-kafka-single.yml

Comment: `zk-single-kafka-single.yml` is not part of the `https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python` reporistory. Issue could be in this compose file.

Comment: that was a zip file. i download it and then use

Comment: The compose you provided works for me, something is wrong with your docker setup, are you connected to the internet?

Comment: `bitnami/kafka`  is its own container

Confluent images that you've added in your Compose are not related.

Python is not a requirement for Docker or Kafka. So what's your actual question?